# Counting tournaments with ties

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

An improper tournament, or tournament with ties, is a graph in which every pair of nodes is connected by a single uniquely directed edge or by a single undirected edge.
There are 1, 2, and 7 improper tournaments of orders 1, 2, and 3, respectively. How many are there of order 4? Of order n?

Comment: There are $3^{\binom{n}{2}}$ labelled improper tournaments, since each edge has three options.  I'm pretty convinced that almost all of these should have no non-trivial automorphisms (this is true for simple graphs, and having directions should only make it harder to have an automorphism), which suggests that the number of improper tournaments on $n$ vertices up to isomorphism should be roughly $\frac{3^{\binom{n}{2}}}{n!}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are looking for in the number of [oriented graphs](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OrientedGraph.html) on $n$ vertices. Just think of an undirected edge in an improper tournament as a missing edge in an oriented graph and vice versa. The number of oriented graphs on $n$ vertices is [OEIS A001174](https://oeis.org/A001174). Note there are $7$ oriented graphs for $n=3$ vertices (not $6$). All $7$ are shown in the first link.

You may also be interested in the paper [The number of oriented graphs](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.mmj/1028997952) by Frank Harary. There are also the papers [Asymptotic formulas for the number of oriented graphs](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S009589567680010X) and [Asymptotic formulas for the number of oriented graphs](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0095895678900588) (two papers both with same title).